# Can't horizontally align a div

Tags: html, css, center

I am adding some new features to this website [here](https://www.camerabeanbags.co.uk/) and have added a cookies notice.

As you can see this is currently at the bottom of the page.

Now I want to have this only around 1500px wide and the whole notice centered. I have tried loads of techniques to achieve this but it seems to be centering to the left and this is possibly because of the live chat window. I'm not too sure why this is occurring or how i can bypass this at all.

This is the most recent code I have tried

```
#cookie-notice.cn-bottom.wp-default {
color: #fff;
font-family: lato;
font-style: normal;
height: 80px;
font-size: 16px;
background-color: #406639 !important;
/* display: block; */
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
/* width: 50%; */
```

Something else I have tried to achieve is when putting the option in the plugin for the cookies notice to be at the top, this overlaps the green top-nav that is already there. I have tried using `position:relative` and `position:absolute` and other CSS to try and get this to be floating at the top of the page and not overlapping anything. So the order would be as below

- COOKIES NOTICE
- GREEN TOP-BAR
- NAV-BAR

then when cookies are agreed-to, the notice will disappear, and the green top-bar will be at the top. When trying this, the cookies-notice and green top-bar just overlap.

Comment: Don't add links to sites. Add an image if necessary, or better, the code that produces the issue.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

Removing height from your `#cookie-notice` div and adding top/bottom padding would be better approach to solve this issue. Try this code.

```
#cookie-notice.cn-bottom.wp-default {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: lato;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #406639 !important;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
```